# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=APIKEY.json 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' is not recognized as an internal or external

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-vision, anaconda3

I want to use google API using python by Anaconda prompt.
I have followed these steps but it is giving me the error 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have created the APIKEY.json file perfectly but in anaconda prompt GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=APIKEY.json is not working.

I have followed these steps.

1. Created a Service account and run all the steps on anaconda prompt.
2. changed the path for the APIKEY.json file.
3. run GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=APIKEY.json this line.

The last command is giving me the error 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the environment variable

from terminal like this

```sh
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/path/to/your/APIKEY.json'
```

or from your code like this

```py
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/path/to/your/APIKEY.json"
```