# After already being set in Pycharm terminal, I still get: Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pycharm, bq

I'm trying to create a bq client python.

I have created the GCP json key and exported it to`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

I have tried to run the following in the PyCharm IDE:

> > export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/.....7e7a385.json"
> > echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
> > /home/...7e7a385.json
> > GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/....7e7a385.json"

(following this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/67224391/311130)

I still get this error afterwards:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the quotes from the export command

Comment: You ran with the "Run" button  or in the terminal with "python main.py" ?
If you run with the "Run" button, you need to set this variable in "Environment" in the "Run/Debug Configurations" of the project. Also you set this variable in code like https://stackoverflow.com/a/69131556/4979811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set it under the IDEA UI: `Edit configuration`